# How do you write sentences when referring to sections (of a webpage)?

Tags: punctuation, reference

If my webpage has sections (ex: internal clients, external clients, feedback), how should I be referring to those sections within a sentence?

**The text would NOT be links (clickable).**

> 1. To view your mail, visit the "Internal clients" section.
> 2. To view your mail, visit the **internal clients** section.
> 3. To view your mail, visit the *internal clients* section.
> 4. To view your mail, visit the Internal clients section.

Are any of the above sentences *incorrect*? Are there any that are *more* correct than others?

I read some similar answers and it appears using quotations is the correct answer, but I wanted to know if it was *wrong* or *less correct* to go with another solution.

Comment: Is "Internal Clients" clickable?

Comment: Since you can create hotlinks, presumably you would and so would thus say, "To view your mail, click *here*."  When the page comes up with "Internal Clients" scrawled across the top, they'll know the name of the page.  However, most people don't care what you decide to name a section of a web page.  That is not need-to-know information.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy sorry, no the link is not clickable as per the request of the client. I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Is it called "Internal Clients" because that section is for the use of these people who are your internal clients? That's a strange wording, otherwise, and very confusing. And why is "Internal" capitalized, but "clients" is not?

Comment: I think the bottom line is, your question is less about language and more about website design and clarity. :)

Comment: Please, for the love of all things Ishkur, hyperlink the document if at all possible. It's obscenely easy and critical the operation of a well maintained website and positive user experience.

Comment: I agree with many people here regarding wording and capitalization. Please understand that this is beyond my control as I have a stubborn business client. The one thing I can control is how to style the text (without hyperlinking it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3C has a [clear guideline](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere) on this regard, assuming that "Internal Clients" calls the user to action. According to that, your sentence becomes

> To view your mail, visit the ***Internal Clients*** section

where "Internal Clients" is written in title case and is hyper-linked to the section.

**Update:** Answer updated according to OP's context. A non clickable text would still be written in title case with noticeable font/style change to make it stand out.

Comment: Sorry my fault for not clarifying; it would not be a link as per client requirements.

Comment: @Othya - Please see my updated answer. I have bold italicized the text using this site's formatting options. Of course, you can design the UI according to the wire-frames/mock-ups provided by your client.

Answer (score 0):

- Internal Clients, view mail [here](http://#).
- 1. Sign in to [Internal Clients](http://#)
  2. Click Mail
- To view your mail, go to Clients > Internal Clients and click Mail.